# Copy Paste within an access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am importing a massive data to a table called "Incident_Timeline_Temp" from an excel sheet. Excel sheet contains "Incident_Date, Incident_Time, Details" columns. The table also has the exact columns along with 2 other columns. I can import the data into the table fine. But the "Details" column in the excel sheet has multiple lines of data, while the date and time for that particular "detail" is a single liner. Therefore, when importing the data, it creates multiple blank lines for date and time until it finds the next line of data and time.

I am trying to create an update query within Access to eliminate the empty lines.
In the picture below, After the date 2017-07-31  4:08 PM there are 4 blank lines until 2017-07-31 5:05 PM. I would like to copy each line in details column that has no date and time and paste it along with 2017-07-31 "details" line and delete the lines with no data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve that simply by one Update query, because Access can not relate the empty records to the corresponding (for a human obvious) record.

You need to build in vba code a loop, running through the **thoroughly sorted records** and combining the Details columns and delete them.

Anyway, this is the least thing I would recommend.

First you should check, if the column "Details" is a Memo field. You mentioned this is in Access a "single liner", so there is no "return" (google for line feed or carriage return) possible! Change to Memo field and import again.

Second, you could try to import from Excel again, after changing the line feed **in Excel** to a space, dash or "Return" Access can read correctly, [like here](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/883258-forced-line-breaks-excel-do-not-import-correctly-into-access). You should also change "Details" to memo field first.